# The meaning of ' action'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I have a sentence

> Action Oil's profits are disappointingly low this year.

I have lookep up **action** in some dictionaries but couldn't find any suitable meanings for it in this sentence. I also don't know the role of  it in this case. I wonder if **action profit** is a phrase, but I couldn't find any examples of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word 'Action' in that phrase simply forms part of the company's name, **Action Oil**.

Otherwise, you're correct to think that the sentence wouldn't make sense.